# Modifying properties/metadata of .mkv files

Tags: windows, video, metadata, matroska, properties

I tried to modify the `Tags` property by right-clicking an `.mkv` file and then selecting Properties - Details, like I did for other filetypes (like .mp4), but I was not able to do the same in that case.

Is there a way to modify the properties of `.mkv` files? (I am interested in properties that I can see as columns in File Explorer)

Comment: More info on this tool....https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvpropedit.html

Comment: Actual download site...http://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html

Comment: I don't think i can modify properties that I can see as columns in File Explorer (like `Tags`), using mkvpropedit

Comment: If you do not try you will never know.

Comment: I have run it using `-l, --list-property-names` option that lists all known and editable property names. That's why I'm telling that.